# sent_tokenize returns a list with only one item

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I'm doing project for a university course on Python for linguists.
For my final project I'm doing all sorts of treatment with Hamlet in a txt file using NLTK.

The problem is, it comes to a point where sent_tokenize returns all the text as a single item in a list.

The text I'm working with looks like this (but is the entire play):

FRANCISCO
For this relief much thanks   tis bitter cold
And I am sick at heart

BERNARDO
Have you had quiet guard

FRANCISCO
Not a mouse stirring

BERNARDO
Well  good night
If you do meet Horatio and Marcellus
The rivals of my watch  bid them make haste

FRANCISCO
I think I hear them  Stand  ho  Who s there

What I tried to do is:

```
hamlet_sentence_tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(hamlet)
number_of_sentences = len(hamlet_sentence_tokens)
strnumber_of_sentences = str(number_of_sentences)
print(number_of_sentences)
```

But no matter what I do, the output is always 1.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: It now seems to me that sent_tokenize doesn't work without punctuation, is that the case?

Comment: Welcome to SO :)
It seems the `sent_tokenize` is only seeking for sentences that end with `.` so one of the easiest ways to work around would be to replace `/n` with './n'. Another solution is extending the built-in tokenizer class.